# Display hide success fail alert

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular 5`. What I want to do is to display a success/ or fail `Alert` based on the block of code executed as shown below.

`showerror` is a boolean.

```
 ...
.subscribe(data =>{
        this.showerror = false
    },
      error =>{
        this.showerror = true
      }
    );
```

My HTML looks like this: All I want to do is to either display one of the following success/fail code blocks depending on the result that's outputted from the above `TS` code. Can someone help me out here.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" [hidden]="{{showerror}}">
  success !! you did it
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="{{showerror}}">
  Fail!!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" [hidden]="!showerror">
    success !! you did it
  </div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="showerror">
  Fail!!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the annotation **`{{}}`**,

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" [hidden]="showerror">
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to display either the success or the fail alert. I guess its a more a logic issue here. What's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try customize `$mdDialog` like this:-

```
 ...
.subscribe(data =>{
        alert = $mdDialog.alert()
                  .title('success !! you did it')
                  .ok('Close');
                  $mdDialog.show(alert).finally(function() {
                      alert = undefined;
                    });;
    },
      error =>{
        alert = $mdDialog.alert()
                  .title('Fail!!!')
                  .ok('Close');
                  $mdDialog.show(alert).finally(function() {
                      alert = undefined;
                    });;
      }
    );
```

Comment: I want to handle all UI from the HTML side and not mix both HTML and typescript togeather. Sorry I am a newbie.